# How to display text while doing work in PHP?

Tags: php

How do I show "loading" text in PHP while code (like a massive database query) is running?

Comment: This could be a good place to start:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305260/how-to-show-ajax-loading-gif-animation-while-the-page-is-loading

Comment: I second that. This looks like a possible duplicate.

Comment: that has nothing to do with php...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn off output buffering and output the html and then start your big code.

```
apache_setenv('no-gzip', 1);
ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 0);
//if you are buffering output currently. Output buffering can be nested.
for ($i = 0; $i < ob_get_level(); $i++) { ob_end_flush(); } 
ob_implicit_flush(1);
```

Safari and IE have a 1k buffer, you probably have to fill that before by outputting blanks for example.

Answer (score 3):

You can use AJAX calls.

1. Browser shows "loading text"
2. Browser processes AJAX request
3. When the response would come back, "loading text" disappears and you can do something (for example Redirect to somewhere)

Comment: [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) is written in javascript

Answer (score 0):

With AJAX you can do it with help of Jquery library.

```
  <html>
    <head>

       <tittle>Page Tittle</tittle>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jQuery.min.js"></script>
      function loadingAjax(div_id)  //javascript function
       {  
        $("#"+div_id).html('<img src="ajax-loader.gif"> saving...');  
           // image displayed when the request started
        $.ajax({  
            type: "POST",  
            url: "script.php",        //php script that will return the database result
            data: "name=John&id=28",  
            success: function(msg){  
                $("#"+div_id).html(msg);  //result displayed after success
            }  
        });  
       } 
</head>
<body>
<a href="#" onclick="loadingAjax('myDiv');">save page</a>  
<div id="myDiv"></div>  
</body>
```

Here the image "ajax_loader.gif" will be displayed till your result from the database is ready.

Hope it helps.